# asp.net c# redirecting from http to https

Tags: asp.net, http, https

So in my code I want to detect if my login page is being called http, and redirect it to https.

I know there are non code ways to skin this cat, but for frustrating technical reasosn I'm backed into doing it in code.

```
            if (!Request.IsSecureConnection)
            {
                string redirectUrl = Request.Url.ToString().Replace("http:", "https:");
                Response.Redirect(redirectUrl);
            }
```

So I drop this in my `Page_Load(...)`, make sure my debugger uses real IIS, not VS2008s IIS, and hit debug.

Inthe debugger, waltz along, hit 
Response.Redirect("https://localhost/StudentPortal3G/AccessControl/AdLogin.aspx"), 
hit f5.

Get "Internet Explorere Cannot Display the webpage, url is HTTP, not HTTPS.
Not getting an informative error... same thing happens not running in the debugger.

So what am I missing? it does not appear to be rocket science, I've seen similar code on lots of blogs...

What am I doing wrong? I figure it has to be a totally obvious Rookie mistake, but I'm not seeing it.

Comment: Turn off "show friendly error messages" in IE and see what it says.  If "friendly" (and I use that term loosely) error messages are turned on and IE gets a non-200 status code AND the information is less than 512 bytes, it turns on the blinders.

Comment: Try including http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.scheme.aspx to process protocol.

Comment: @Chris - I turn that setting off and still get the same error. Any ideas how to get informative errors?

Comment: @StackOverflowException - I'm not sure I understand this answer, you mean use the constants "Uri.UriSchemeHttps" instead of "http' and "https"? I've tried it both ways...

Answer (score 87, accepted):

I'd do a `!Request.IsLocal` as well to make sure that I'm not debugging, though if you're using a real instance of IIS with a cert applied when debugging that shouldn't be an issue.

```
if (!Request.IsLocal && !Request.IsSecureConnection)
{
    string redirectUrl = Request.Url.ToString().Replace("http:", "https:");
    Response.Redirect(redirectUrl, false);
    HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
}
```

Note: This answer assumes an MVC context within a Controller where `HttpContext` is a property holding the current context.  If you're unlucky enough to still be using WebForms or are referencing the context in a degenerate way you will need to use `HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()`.

Note: I've updated this to be consistent with the recommended pattern to terminate the request according to the [framework documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

> When you use this method in a page handler to terminate a request for
>   one page and start a new request for another page, set endResponse to
>   false and then call the CompleteRequest method. If you specify true
>   for the endResponse parameter, this method calls the End method for
>   the original request, which throws a ThreadAbortException exception
>   when it completes. This exception has a detrimental effect on Web
>   application performance, which is why passing false for the
>   endResponse parameter is recommended. For more information, see the
>   End method.

Comment: There is just one problem with that redirect: session variables could be lost.

Comment: @The_Ghost how so? I'm not sure what you're getting at.

Comment: without "false" as a second argument to Response.Redirect, session variables will be lost. I have experienced the same problem already.

Comment: @The_Ghost - that only seems like if you're attempting to set those in code that would execute after the response is terminated. Microsoft does recommend using `false`, though, because of performance issues and I will update.

Comment: Even though this post is old, I got this working by replacing `HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();` with `HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();`.

Comment: @zulq my answer assumes that there is an `HttpContext` variable that is the current context. If you don't have that available (say in WebForms), then you'd need to use `HttpContext.Current`

Comment: One slight problem reading `Request.Url.ToString()`, is if the querystring contains any URL Encoded parameters, it will decode them and screw up the redirect. E.g. `mypage.aspx?q=a%3D1%26b%3D2%26c%3D3` will get redirected as `mypage.aspx?q=a=1&b=2&c=3`.

Comment: @tvanfosson Thank you. very helpful. does this lines of codes. , solve th Canonical url problem too?

Answer (score 25):

I usually call the following from the OnPreInit in a base class that all my pages inherit from. Of course, you could just do this in every page...but you wouldn't want to do that now would you?

Note that I've got two properties for each page so that I can specify the SSL requirement for each page (RequiresSSL) while I can also override and redirect check if I want (with IgnoreRequiresSSL, which is helpful for pages like error pages that you rewrite to and don't know whether they'll be encrypted or not), but of course, you can remove these for simple setups.

```
    protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreInit(e);

        if (!IsPostBack)
            RedirectAccordingToRequiresSSL();

        ...
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Redirect if necessary to ssl or non-ssl enabled URL dependant on RequiresSSL property setting.
    /// </summary>
    private void RedirectAccordingToRequiresSSL()
    {
        if (IgnoreRequiresSSL) return;

        if (RequiresSSL)
        {
            if (!Request.IsSecureConnection) // Need to redirect to https
                RedirectAccordingToRequiresSSL(Uri.UriSchemeHttps);
        }
        else if (Request.IsSecureConnection)
        {
            RedirectAccordingToRequiresSSL(Uri.UriSchemeHttp);
        }

        // Otherwise don't need to do any redirecting as already using the correct scheme
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Redirect as requested to specified scheme
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="scheme"></param>
    private void RedirectAccordingToRequiresSSL(string scheme)
    {
        var url = scheme + Uri.SchemeDelimiter + Request.Url.Authority + Request.Url.PathAndQuery;
        Response.Redirect(url, false);
    }
```

Comment: This is clearly a better soloution, and I read your article when searching, but until the "ugly" soloution I implemented works, this will not either, correct? because in the end the both ResponseRedirect from http to https "manually", am i correct?

Comment: Yes. Your core issue is not having a cert properly installed and assigned to the site - if you need help with that, then ask.

Comment: +1 for being helpful, and having a better general purpose soloution, even though I went with the marked answer above.

Comment: Thanks, your clean and painless solution I implemented on a complex site in minutes; whereas yesterday I struggled for hours unsuccessfully trying to implement an equivalent using URL Rewrite Rules in the web.config.  Your solution works fine with aspx Login Controls and Membership, including the redirects in the query strings.  I could not get a set of Rewrite Rules to work--maybe that's part my lack of understanding, but the supporting documentation could be more helpful.  Also your solution to me is more helpful than one with more votes because your solution goes both ways: https<-->http.

Answer (score 12):

In my opinion the following is the best all-round approach.

Three reasons

1. It works for both `MVC` and `Web API` as it is done at `IIS` level.
2. It does not effect local / debug settings. (permanent redirect can mess you around when debugging non `https` sites on your pc).
3. Uses a permanent redirect, so all future requests will automatically go to `https`

Simply add the following to your `<system.webServer>` section in your 'Web.config' for your project.

```
 <system.webServer>
 ....

 <rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="localhost" negate="true" />
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
  <outboundRules>
    <rule name="Add Strict-Transport-Security when HTTPS" enabled="true">
      <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Strict_Transport_Security" pattern=".*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" ignoreCase="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" value="max-age=31536000" />
    </rule>
  </outboundRules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: This answer is fine, except the `<rewrite>` tag goes into `<system.webServer>`.

Comment: @FranzWimmer where should it go? If no in the `<system.webserver>`

Comment: Note: you need to install the Rewrite module for this to work, otherwise you just get 500 errors - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

Answer (score 8):

You can also use the new UriBuilder:

```
Dim context As HttpContext = HttpContext.Current
If Not context.Request.IsSecureConnection Then
    Dim secureUrl As New UriBuilder(context.Request.Url)
    secureUrl.Scheme = "https"
    secureUrl.Port = 443
    context.Response.Redirect(secureUrl.ToString, False)
    Return
End If
```

C#

```
HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
if (!context.Request.IsSecureConnection)
{
    UriBuilder secureUrl = new UriBuilder(context.Request.Url);
    secureUrl.Scheme = "https";
    secureUrl.Port = 443;
    context.Response.Redirect(secureUrl.ToString(), false);
}
```

Comment: This is much better coz you can use the port other than the default 443.

Answer (score 3):

One of the ways that I was able to enforce an https redirect is to the following:

In the app pool I have my application running on just port 443 so that there is no possiblity for an unencrypted session to occur (unless encryption scheme is broken through a vulnerability..). I created another application on port 80 with the same IP address which contains just a **web.config** file with the following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="https://yourWebsiteURL.com" />
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: This is a great solution but needs HttpRedirect optional install - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httpredirect/

Answer (score 2):

Here's my solution:

```
// Force HTTPS connection
if (!Request.IsSecureConnection)
{
    var uri = new Uri(Request.Url.ToString());
    var redirectUrl = Settings.CanonicalDomain + uri.PathAndQuery;
    Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
    Response.AddHeader("Location", redirectUrl);
    Response.End();
}
```

Where `Settings.CanonicalDomain` is your HTTPS hostname.  It 301 redirects which may be the proper response in some cases.

Answer (score 2):

I would also suggest tvalfonsso's solution, but with a small modification in case you have some url rewriting (RawUrl differs from Url)

```
    if (SPPage == SPPages.StartAutotrading && !Request.IsLocal && !Request.IsSecureConnection)
        {
            string redirectUrl = (Request.Url.ToString().Replace(Request.Url.PathAndQuery.ToString(), "") + Request.RawUrl).Replace("http:", "https:");
            Response.Redirect(redirectUrl);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

*disclaimer - I was involved in the development of this project*

I would recommend using http://nuget.org/packages/SecurePages/ It gives you the ability to secure specific pages or use Regex to define matches. It will also force all pages not matching the Regex or directly specified back to HTTP.

You can install it via NuGet: `Install-Package SecurePages`

Docs are here: https://github.com/webadvanced/Secure-Page-manager-for-asp.net#secure-pages

Simple Usage:

```
SecurePagesConfiguration.Urls.AddUrl("/cart");
```

or

```
SecurePagesConfiguration.Urls.AddRegex(@"(.*)account", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.

Comment: Cool, someone should go back and tell everyone who has ever self promoted their work on S.O to add that disclaimer for the sake of fairness...

Answer (score 1):

On my development environment, I like to have a separate publish directory with IIS installed with a self signed cert, which is different form my code directory without a cert that I debug directly inside of Visual Studio. In this scenario `!Request.IsLocal` isn't ideal because it doesn't work anywhere on your development environment, even in the IIS directory with the cert. I prefer this:

```
if (!IsPostBack && !HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled) 
{
    // do http->https and https->http redirection here
}
```

`HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled` is based on the value of compilation debug="true/false" in your web.config. I have it set to true in my code directory, and false in my publish directory when I need to test http and https redirection locally.

I add in the `IsPostBack` simply to make it (slightly) more efficient by skipping the extra ssl checking when not needed.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to get IIS to do it without using Rewrite:

1. IIS SSL Settings: Set SSL Required.
2. IIS Error Pages: Change the IIS 403 Error code to redirect to the https url.

You can also add from the web.config in the HttpErrors section.