# DNN redirect to https

Tags: ssl, dotnetnuke

We have a self-hosted DNN 6.01.03 site, in Windows 2003x64, std.

We have enabled it to use SSL, but we would like to set it up so an user coming through HTTP gets redirected to HTTPs.

Is there a way to do that? It seems that in IIS7 we could use the IIS Rewrite URL module, but this is IIS6.

Please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fastest way is to set the site to "Force SSL" in DNN.

I have noticed that the behavior is better when using a tool like UrlMaster from IFinity.com.au.

Comment: Do you mean the "SSL Enforced" setting in the Site Settings, Advanced Settings section? the description of that setting is "When this option is set, Pages which are not marked as secure will not be accessible with SSL ( HTTPS )". That's not the behavior I am looking for (I tested it and it works as the description indicates).

Comment: Jose - Mitchel is correct here, and this is the accepted way of handling the conversion of http->https.  What you need to is change the setting to 'enforce SSL', but you also have to mark all your pages as 'secure'.  This is a setting in the pages, but you should be able to change the setting for all pages by Sql if you want all pages to be secure.

Comment: +1 for the clarification. I will try this one too. However, at the moment the solution to redirect 403.4 is better for me because it is more convenient to keep local requests in HTTP (and I can accomplish that with the JavaScript solution).

Comment: Here is a SQL script in case you cannot login due to the SSL Enforced setting.

  `UPDATE dbo.PortalSettings
  SET SettingValue = 'False' 
  WHERE PortalID = 0 AND SettingName = 'SSLEnforced' OR SettingName = 'SSLEnabled'`

Answer (score 3):

Set up a redirect page and point 403.4 errors there. The redirect page will be the only url that **doesn't** enforce SSL.

#### 1. Create a redirect page

You can use pretty much any available web technology here.

Examples:

- [client-side html/js](http://www.jppinto.com/index.php/2009/01/automatically-redirect-http-requests-to-https-on-iis-6/) (requires javascript)
- [Classic ASP](http://blog.opsan.com/2005/04/30/iis-redirect-from-http-to-https/)

In ASP.NET, the redirect.aspx can be written in a similar way to which it is done in Classic ASP:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<script runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {   
        if (!Request.IsSecureConnection)
        {
            string query = Request.ServerVariables["QUERY_STRING"];
            query = query.Replace("http:", "https:");
            query = query.Replace("403;", "");
            query = query.Replace(":80", "");
            Response.Redirect(query);
        }
    }
</script> 

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        Redirecting...
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

#### 2. Check that SSL is not enforced on the redirect page

[image: Edit redirect.aspx propertis in IIS Manager]

#### 3. Point 403.4 errors to the redirect page url

[image]

#### See also:

- [asp.net c# redirecting from http to https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5305443/asp-net-c-sharp-redirecting-from-http-to-https)
- [Automatically Redirect HTTP requests to HTTPS on IIS 6](http://www.jppinto.com/index.php/2009/01/automatically-redirect-http-requests-to-https-on-iis-6/)
- [IIS: Redirect from http to https](http://blog.opsan.com/2005/04/30/iis-redirect-from-http-to-https/)

Comment: Note: I tried the aspx sample and it didn't work. For it  to work correctly it seems that you cannot redirect to URL (because the Request changes, so when the .aspx process it, it converts http://{mysite}/redirect.aspx to https://{mysite}/redirect.aspx (which is not what I wanted, I wanted to go to the originally requested URL). Using [links](http://www.jppinto.com/index.php/2009/01/automatically-redirect-http-requests-to-https-on-iis-6/) you posted I used the javascript example and that works great. Please note that you should use "Message Type" = "File" when setting the custom error in IIS.

Comment: I rewrote the .aspx example using the Classic ASP version as a template. Tested, and it works in the same way now.

Answer (score 1):

To help others: The answer here comes in 2 parts from 2 different people:

1) As Mitchel state, go to your DNN site setting, Enable SSL and Enforce SSL. Site Settings > Advanced Settings > SSL Settings > Check both, "Enable SSL and Enforce SSL"

[image: Site Settings]

2) As Bruce pointed out, you then have to go to each page and make it a secure page. Page Settings > Other Settings > check "Secure". I had to do this for all of the pages... even Site Admin and Settings Pages.

[image: Page Settings]

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a redirect in `Global.asax` to force redirect of **ALL** page request on the hosted domain. This will have higher priority than any DNN settings.

```
<script RunAt="server">
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // ENABLE SSL REDIRECTS
  if (!HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection)
  {
    Response.Redirect("https://" + Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"] + HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl);
  }
}
</script>
```

Or if you are using custom headers or load balancers

```
<script RunAt="server">
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // ENABLE SSL REDIRECTS
  if (!string.Equals(Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-Proto"], "https", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
  {
    Response.Redirect("https://" + Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"] + HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl);
  }
}
</script>
```