# asp hyperlink and https

Tags: c#, asp.net, https

I have an asp.net page with alot of hyperlinks which leads to different pages.
I need one of these pages to be redirected as https, and not just http.
Generally I've been using NavigateUrl property with the name of the page, but I could find any way of redirecting to a new page with hyperlink using https.

Is it possible to redirect from asp:hyperlink control to another page using https?

Thanks

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/422327/www-and-HTTPS-redirect .. maybe this might help a bit..

Comment: Tweak: Replace http with https and redirect. Look at 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5305443/asp-net-c-sharp-redirecting-from-http-to-https

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, [asp:LinkButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.aspx) is the answer.