# Simplest way to Force HTTPS during Page_Init

Tags: c#, asp.net, https, security, httpcontext

On very few pages of my site i want to make sure they can only be accessed though HTTPS connections. What is the best way of accomplishing that. All the examples i see seem like they are trying to do it for the whole site.

I was hoping of finding a way to accomplish that on `Page_Init` or `Page_Preload`.

And redirect to Https version

Comment: Do you want to deny access if HTTP is attempted? or do you want to redirect to an HTTPS version?

Comment: Redirect version please

Comment: I think this is covered in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5305443/asp-net-c-sharp-redirecting-from-http-to-https

Comment: Yes it seems like it is Google didn't find that :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could access the [`IsSecureConnection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.issecureconnection.aspx) property of the request and redirect:

```
if (!Request.IsSecureConnection) {
    Response.Redirect(...);
}
```

You may have references to pages you want to redirect to, or you can construct an https Uri from the `Request.Url` parts, and so on, but there above you have the check.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use HTTP Strict Transport Security.

For further details please have a look here:

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security

Any questions, just let me know.

Thanks
Fabio
@fcerullo