# Set SSL after Login/Authentication in Kentico

Tags: content-management-system, kentico

I have requirement that once user has logged in and is authenticated URL should be changed to SSL and when he logs out url is back to HTTP.

I am aware about Properties in webpart where we can set YES/NO/INHERITS/NEVER.

I am able to set HTTPS permanently but not dynamically.

Any suggestion/help is appreciated.

Comment: To clarify - are we talking about live site (not editing ui - cmsdesk or sitemanager)?

Comment: Yes, its Live site.
We have Login section in live which takes us to some member area.

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that you want to use SSL depending on whether the user is logged in and not on document he is currently browsing, yes?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.
Suppose I have 5 documents, and one myaccount page.
If user is not logged in he sees 5 documents as http and myaccount is access denied, once is logsin all these document goes as https and myaccount is accessible wiht https.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of any functionality within Kentico to do this, but you should be able to create a webpart and place it on the masterpage. This web part would just check the current user, and if there is a user that is logged in redirect to https version and vice versa.

You could also add some logic to make sure it doesn't do this in the the edit tab in cmsdesk.

You can check the user with

```
CMSContext.CurrentUser
```

Some help with redirecting to the secure page can be found at

[asp.net c# redirecting from http to https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5305443/asp-net-c-sharp-redirecting-from-http-to-https)

Comment: Yes, we have this option if we need to customize it.
Was wondering if Kentico gives some option.

Comment: No, there is no such out-of-box functionality like this. You will have to create your own sign-in/sign-out web part that will cover your scenario.

Comment: Would this have to be a web part or could this check be done in the .NET master page?

Comment: You could do it either. Personally I'm more in favour of doing it on a webpart so it could easily be reused on any future site and easily implemented into a site using the portal engine development model.

Comment: Finally I have implemented it, added a webpart which is further called in master page, which just checks that user is authenticated and it takes you to https

Answer (score 0):

As rocky said there is not functionality out of the box that will do this for you.

You need to create a web part like it was suggested by Lukek that checks that the user is logged in and redirects them to the https address.

The code below will redirect.

```
if (!Request.IsLocal && !Request.IsSecureConnection)
{
    string redirectUrl = Request.Url.ToString().Replace("http:", "https:");
    Response.Redirect(redirectUrl);
}
```

As suggested bu lukek you need to check the CMSContext.CurrentUser however I would also use the HttpContext.User property.

That will enforce the request to be https.