# IIS Re-write http to https with subfolders

Tags: http, redirect, iis, url-rewriting, subdirectory

As simple as it sounds and as much as I've searched, I'm not able to get

http://example.com/subfolder to redirect to https://example.com/subfolder using IIS rewrite.

Note: This is only when "**http**" is explicitly stated in the browser.

```
<rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Found" />enter code here
```

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [asp.net c# redirecting from http to https](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5305443/asp-net-c-sharp-redirecting-from-http-to-https)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your rule is that `REQUEST_URI` in your redirect action is the whole URI as requested.  What you want is the result of the rule match.  `R1` will give you this.  [This answer gives a good explanation of the rule back-references](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17010848/571637).  A working rule can be constructed like this:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS Redirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```